# Sprite is not moving in proper position based on where user taps

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

It seems when I click to go right or left, the sprite does as intended. However when I click to the bottom in hopes it goes down, it actually goes up. And when I do the same thing vice versa, it goes down. I simply just want to make it so the user can navigate the sprite around properly depending where they touch on the screen.

Code:

```
- (void)setCenterOfScreen:(CGPoint) position {
    CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] viewSize];

    int x = MAX(position.x, screenSize.width/2);
    int y = MAX(position.y, screenSize.height/2);

    x = MIN(x, theMap.mapSize.width * theMap.tileSize.width - screenSize.width/2);
    y = MIN(y, theMap.mapSize.height * theMap.tileSize.height - screenSize.height/2);

    CGPoint goodPoint = ccp(x,y);

    CGPoint centerOfScreen = ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2);
    CGPoint difference = ccpSub(centerOfScreen, goodPoint);
    self.position = difference;
}
- (void) setPlayerPosition:(CGPoint)position
{
    mainChar.position = position;
}
-(void) touchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchLoc = [touch locationInNode:self];
    touchLoc = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLoc];
    touchLoc = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLoc];

    CGPoint playerPos = mainChar.position;
    CGPoint diff = ccpSub(touchLoc, playerPos);

    // Move horizontal or vertical?
    if (abs(diff.x) > abs(diff.y))
    {
        if (diff.x > 0)
        {
            playerPos.x += theMap.tileSize.width;
        }
        else
        {
            playerPos.x -= theMap.tileSize.width;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (diff.y > 0)
        {
            playerPos.y += theMap.tileSize.height;

        }
        else
        {
            playerPos.y -= theMap.tileSize.height;

        }
    }

    if (playerPos.x <= (theMap.mapSize.width * theMap.tileSize.width) &&
        playerPos.y <= (theMap.mapSize.height * theMap.tileSize.height) &&
        playerPos.y >= 0 &&
        playerPos.x >= 0)
    {
        [self setPlayerPosition:playerPos];
    }
    [self setCenterOfScreen:mainChar.position];
}
```

Comment: portrait or landscape? cocos2d 2.x or 3.x? is this the first scene? If so try adding a scene begore that to test if this is the common width/height flipped issue that appears only in the first scene in 2.x

Comment: This is landscape, cocos2d 3.x, and this is the second scene, first scene after the menu scene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is moving up that should be moving down? Is it the sprite or the layer? If it is the layer and is caused by your setCenterOfScreen method then...

Where you have:

```
CGPoint difference = ccpSub(centerOfScreen, goodPoint);
```

Try:

```
CGPoint difference = ccpSub(goodPoint, centerOfScreen);
```

Just to make it easy to visualize, image the Y of centerOfScreen is 10 and the goodPoint is 5 (meaning the touch is under the center). 10 - 5 = 5. So if you are adding that delta to the layer's/scene's current Y which starts at 0 initially, it will go up and not down like you're expecting since you just essentially made the Y = 5, which moves everything up and not down. Switch them around.

**Update (Edited Answer):**

Based on your comment, the issue is the player. Are you using cocos v3? Why don't you just have:

```
CGPoint touchLoc = [touch locationInNode:self];
```

And leave it at that? Back in versions like v2 I would have done something like:

```
-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint touchPos = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    touchPos = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchPos];

    // Do somthing...
}
```

But in v3 you wouldn't do that. The method locationInNode looks like this...

```
- (CGPoint) locationInNode:(CCNode*) node
{
    CCDirector* dir = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    CGPoint touchLocation = [self locationInView: [self view]];
    touchLocation = [dir convertToGL: touchLocation];
    return [node convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];
}
```

So what you are doing is screwing up the values when you call the convertToGL and convertToNodeSpace methods again after it was already called in locationInNode. locationInNode already does that work for you.

The answer to your problem, remove:

```
touchLoc = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLoc];
touchLoc = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLoc];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The sprite (main char), if I were to say tap above it, it moves down as opposed to up, and up as opposed to down. Doing what you said seemed to shift the layer as well, and then when the player hit the bottom, couldnt move anymore

Comment: I added an update to my answer. You are doing things twice in the conversion which would mess things up in v3. Drop the convert to GL and node space calls in your code.

Comment: Noticed that the sprite won't move outside of the original screen though, I can see the other parts of my map when it scrolls to the end of the intial screen that was loaded, but even clicking on other parts of my map to the right or top don't even call the NSLog I put in on touchBegan which means its not being fired, any ideas?

Comment: Did you debug your code? Where is it stopping from getting to your code that has the NSLog? Is there an if statement that tests if the player is within a certain box first before it proceeds? For example in the code in your OP you have an if statement at the end that sets the player's position only if it falls within that box. Is that if statement and the values it contains correct (did you debug to see if it is or is not)?

Comment: I've tried deleting the if statement at the bottom completely, and just having the set player position there, and that didn't do it either. It just seems to stop letting the users click outside the initial scene screen, i.e., when the camera shifts with the user, anything to the right or top (since map starts at 0,0 so no bottom or left) - you cannot click outside that area as touchEnded isn't called as NSlog is never printed when those areas are clicked

Comment: What class is your touch methods implemented in? Is it the CCScene or something else?

Comment: Yes the CCScene, seems like this would be something so simple, and it's literally preventing me from everything. I've tried remaking projects and implementing the same code as well. Here is the stack over flow I made regarding the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24156092/ontouch-events-not-being-called-when-sprite-moves-off-initial-part-of-map  I haven't used any code aside from what is on that page upon making a new project, so there's not much code to weave through - but I've tried just about everything I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution would be to invert the signal when updating the y:

```
if (diff.y > 0)
   playerPos.y -= theMap.tileSize.height;
else
   playerPos.y += theMap.tileSize.height;
```

You can also change the reference of the position of the mainChar:

```
mainChar.positionType = CCPositionTypeMake(CCPositionUnitPoints, CCPositionUnitPoints, CCPositionReferenceCornerTopLeft);
```

or

```
mainChar.positionType = CCPositionTypeMake(CCPositionUnitPoints, CCPositionUnitPoints, CCPositionReferenceCornerBottomLeft);
```

Depending of the current reference.