# onTouch Events not being called, when sprite moves off initial part of map?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

It appears no onTouch events are being called (put NSLog statements in to confirm) when my player is moved above or to the right of my map. Map is big enough, and you can still see the map slightly when I get to the top or right, as the layer shifts as intended, but when clicking any further then what's initially loaded on screen, no touch events are being fired and char is stuck. Any ideas?

```
- (void)setCenterOfScreen:(CGPoint) position {
    CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] viewSize];

    int x = MAX(position.x, screenSize.width/2);
    int y = MAX(position.y, screenSize.height/2);

    x = MIN(x, theMap.mapSize.width * theMap.tileSize.width - screenSize.width/2);
    y = MIN(y, theMap.mapSize.height * theMap.tileSize.height - screenSize.height/2);

    CGPoint goodPoint = ccp(x,y);

    CGPoint centerOfScreen = ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2);
    CGPoint difference = ccpSub(centerOfScreen, goodPoint);
    self.position = difference;
}
-(void) touchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    CGPoint touchLoc = [touch locationInNode:self];



// NOT CALLED WHEN PLAYER REACHES TOP OR RIGHT OF MAP (INITIAL SCREEN LOAD PART OF MAP) 
      // When clicking any furhter or top on the map, no touch event is fired and character (sprite) doesn't move
        NSLog(@"Touch fired");

    CGPoint playerPos = mainChar.position;
    CGPoint diff = ccpSub(touchLoc, playerPos);

    // Move horizontal or vertical?
    if (abs(diff.x) > abs(diff.y))
    {
        if (diff.x > 0)
        {
            playerPos.x += theMap.tileSize.width;
        }
        else
        {
            playerPos.x -= theMap.tileSize.width;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (diff.y > 0)
        {
            playerPos.y += theMap.tileSize.height;

        }
        else
        {
            playerPos.y -= theMap.tileSize.height;

        }
    }

    if (playerPos.x <= (theMap.mapSize.width * theMap.tileSize.width) &&
        playerPos.y <= (theMap.mapSize.height * theMap.tileSize.height) &&
        playerPos.y >= 0 &&
        playerPos.x >= 0)
    {
        mainChar.position = playerPos;
    }
    [self setCenterOfScreen:mainChar.position];
}
```

Comment: please don't repost essentially the same issue multiple times, instead edit your original post. In this case your problem seems to be that you are not converting the touch coords to gl (converttogl in director) and possibly you need to convertToNodespace of the map as well

Comment: i removed touchLoc = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLoc];
touchLoc = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLoc]; from under CGPoint touchLoc, because I was told that is what locationInNode:self essentially does...

Comment: You're right, I overlooked that, locationInNode does both conversion to GL and conversion to node space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely your scene's content size. I believe you are moving the scene (CCScene) with the call to setCenterOfScreen as you move the player right? If I remember correctly the content size and bounding box for the scene doesn't change as you add children to it. If that is the case (or still the case) then you'll need to set the content size of the scene to the size of your entire level (map). You'll also want to ensure that the lower-left or your map aligns with the lower-left of the scene at (0,0) so that your scene's new bounding box encloses all of your map.

To check, after you've setup the scene CCLOG the scene's content size. If it is not the size of your map then you know that is the problem if you are indeed moving the scene with the call to setCenterOfScreen.

Another solution is to create a root content node that you add to the scene, then you add your game elements to that content node. That way the touch occurs on the scene but when you do the movements you move the content node, not the scene. For example:

```
@implementation YourScene

- (void)onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];

    self.contentNode = [CCNode node];
    [self addChild:self.contentNode];

    CCSprite* bg = ...;
    CCSprite* player = ...;

    [self.contentNode addChild:bg];
    [self.contentNode addChild:player];

    ...
}

- (void)setCenterOfScreen:(CGPoint)position
{
    CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] viewSize];

    int x = MAX(position.x, screenSize.width/2);
    int y = MAX(position.y, screenSize.height/2);

    x = MIN(x, theMap.mapSize.width * theMap.tileSize.width - screenSize.width/2);
    y = MIN(y, theMap.mapSize.height * theMap.tileSize.height - screenSize.height/2);

    CGPoint goodPoint = ccp(x,y);

    CGPoint centerOfScreen = ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2);
    CGPoint difference = ccpSub(centerOfScreen, goodPoint);

    self.contentNode.position = ccpAdd(self.contentNode.position, difference);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried the alternate solution, and it seemed to let me scroll to the left, bottom, and top edges fine - but the right as soon as it scrolled to the edge, the character stopped, however I kept seeing black. I tried the first solution, and did     self.contentSize = theMap.contentSize;
That worked like a charm!!! I can't believe that's all it took ! Thank you so much. Now on my way to try to find a tutorial to create a HUD for Cocos2d v3...! :)